# Parsing a file handle with XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, inputstream, xml-twig

I see in the XML::Twig documentation the functions `parse($text)` for parsing scalars contain xml text, and `parsefile($fileName)` for reading in and parsing xml files. I would like to parse an input stream (a file handle or maybe STDIN). Still wading through documentation and haven't found anything. How should I do this?

Comment: Don't have any experience with any of them from CPAN, but from your description it sounds like you want a SAX parser.

Comment: XML::Twig does SAX and DOM. I'm really just doing the filehandle thing to cover all of my bases in the future.

Comment: XML::Twig is not a SAX parser, but combination stream/tree (i.e. "twig", get it?) oriented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`XML::Twig` is a subclass of `XML::Parser`, so you should be able to pass `parse()` an open `IO::Handle`.

Comment: That's actually in the docs of XML::Twig, but I will make it more explicit that parse can be passed a filehandle.